# How to install XSLT 2.0 processor like Saxon in Cygwin?

Tags: package, cygwin, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0

The standard package for processing XSLT in Cygwin in xsltproc. The problem is that it supports only xslt 1.0. Are there some packages that also support xslt 2.0 in cygwin and how to install them?

Comment: Saxon 9.8 exists in a Java version, a .NET version and also a C/C++ version. I understand cygwin is used on Windows, as every supported Windows versions for years comes with the .NET framework it seems the most straightforwards way to use Saxon 9.8 on Window is to install the .NET version of Saxon 9.8 HE, so download and execute `SaxonHE9-8-0-7N-setup.exe` from https://sourceforge.net/projects/saxon/files/Saxon-HE/9.8/ and then to familiarize yourself with http://saxonica.com/html/documentation/using-xsl/commandline/ e.g. the options of `Transform.exe` it installs.